# Inverse Kinematics (IK) rigging does not work

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

I set up this inverse kinematics (IK) in the left foot of my char rig by following a [YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/hWfUe03Ib5E), but the rig is not working as it is working in the video.

The bone is bending in a different direction.

[blend file download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DjVl7ipwNJCWInHnoftO52fi96MJwDNx/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: there is no armature in your blend file!? and please upload the .blend file, not the .blend1 file. thanks.

Comment: Changed the link to .blend file. I don't know why you didn't see any armature.

Comment: in 2:09 he said: apply scale ...don't forget that. You didn't do that. You should always try to follow every step which the tutorial does. This won't solve your problem, but this prevents having even more problems.

Comment: Thanks buy I need my answer.